# Where can I access Google Play App Historical monthly downloaded data?

Tags: android, api, web-scraping, google-play, data-science

I am working on my school data visualization project, which needs to use historical monthly downloaded data to track on some social media Apps, like Facebook, Twitter and Snapchat.

Someone says this data is available in https://www.androidrank.org/, I checked the [API](https://www.androidrank.org/api/application/com.whatsapp?key=9GmLbwMLMgxz3BeAo3Two0NzeuRVN8Jin6EPcerWVfesQH4BhLuLeUSlETXfrnMd) they offer, it doesn't provide the daily installed data.

On Youtube, I saw some people made the video related to it like [Most Installed Android App from 2011 - 2019](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GTFGQP05Xg0&t=20s)

Does anyone know how can I access this data? Many thanks